# URL rewrite for language query variable to fake directory conversion returns 404 error

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I have surely read and tested all the solutions found on Stackoverflow but couldn't make it work ... so here I am.

I'm trying to transform

> example.com/?l=en

into

> example.com/en/

( /en/ isn't supposed to exist on the server )

I use the following htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)l=en($|&)
RewriteRule ^$ /en/?&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)l=ja($|&)
RewriteRule ^$ /ja/?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Since the last line triggers a 404 error, the errorDocument 404 kicks in.
The rule returns a "page not found" in the browser when I comment the errorDocument line.

Comment: If I understand well, you want to redirect to a folder that doesn't exist and you wonder why it gives a 404?

Comment: Does `example.com/en/` work directly from your browser at present?

Comment: @M.Parent I'm not trying to do a redirection here. I'm only trying to show a better looking URL to the visitor.

Comment: According to http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/ I should use RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?l=$1 [L]  ... which I did but with no result.

Comment: You should approach the problem the other side around. See my answer.

Comment: I've found a workaround by using this :
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^en/?$ index_en.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^ja/?$ index_ja.php [NC,L]
I am going to leave the question open because I still want to know the correct rewrite rule that works for "example.com/?l=en"